# Why multiple selection is not working on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to use multiple selection in my asp page. I have followed pickList from jquery plugin. I have followed this link in given below:

http://jquery-plugins.net/picklist-simple-pick-list-with-jquery-and-bootstrap

This is my asp page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="testWebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/pickList.css"  rel="stylesheet">

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/pickList.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        div.container {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        header, footer {
            padding: 1em;
            color: white;
            background-color:  #8dc060;
            clear: left;
            text-align: center;
        }

        nav {
            float: left;
            max-width: 160px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav ul a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        article {
            margin-left: 170px;
            border-left: 1px solid gray;
            padding: 1em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            li { 
                background:  #90EE90; 


            }
            li:nth-child(odd) { 
                background: #00BFFF; 


            }
            body, html {
          height: 100%;
        }

     </style>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">



    function ShowCurrentValue() {

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var countryname = $("#countryname").val();
        var companyname = $("#companyname").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "testWebForm.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
            data: JSON.stringify({ name: name, countryname: countryname, companyname: companyname }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }

        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {


        var val = {
            01: { id: 01, text: 'Isis' },
            02: { id: 02, text: 'Sophia' },
            03: { id: 03, text: 'Alice' },
            04: { id: 04, text: 'Isabella' },
            05: { id: 05, text: 'Manuela' },
            06: { id: 06, text: 'Laura' },
            07: { id: 07, text: 'Luiza' },
            08: { id: 08, text: 'Valentina' },
            09: { id: 09, text: 'Giovanna' },
            10: { id: 10, text: 'Maria Eduarda' },
            11: { id: 11, text: 'Helena' },
            12: { id: 12, text: 'Beatriz' },
            13: { id: 13, text: 'Maria Luiza' },
            14: { id: 14, text: 'Lara' },
            15: { id: 15, text: 'Julia' }
        };
        var pick = $("#pickList").pickList({ data: val });
        $("#getSelected").click(function () {
            console.log(pick.getValues());
        });



        $("#registration").click(function (e) {

            $("#replace").html('');

            var htmll = "<div>Name: <input type='text' id='name'></div>"+
                        "<div>Country: <input type='text' id='countryname'></div>"+
                        "<div>Company: <input type='text' id='companyname'></div>"+
                        "<div><input type='button' value='Submit' id='submitbtn' onclick='ShowCurrentValue()'></div>";
            $("#replace").append(htmll);



        });





    });
</script> 
</head>
<body style = "font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt">


     <div class="container">

    <header>
       <h1>Demo List</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a id="registration" href="#">Registration</a></li>
        <li><a id="table" href="#">Table</a></li>
        <li><a id="details" href="#">Details</a></li>
        <li><a id="about" href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

     <div class="panel-heading">
               <h3 class="panel-title">PickList Demo</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

               <div id="pickList"></div>

               <br><br>
               <button class="btn btn-primary" id="getSelected">Get Selected</button>
            </div>
         </div>
    <div id="replace">
       <img src="images/wallpaper.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <footer>Copyright &copy; prangroup.com</footer>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It shows error:

> testWebForm.aspx:117 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pickList is not a
>   function
>       at HTMLDocument. (testWebForm.aspx:117)
>       at Function. (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19)
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:12)
>       at Function.ready (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19)
>       at HTMLDocument. (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19) (anonymous) @ testWebForm.aspx:117 (anonymous) @ jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19 each @
>   jquery-1.3.2.min.js:12 ready @ jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19 (anonymous) @
>   jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.pickList = function(options) {

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.pickList.defaults, options);

    this.fill = function() {
      var option = '';

      $.each(opts.data, function(key, val) {
        option += '<option id=' + val.id + '>' + val.text + '</option>';
      });
      this.find('#pickData').append(option);
    };
    this.controll = function() {
      var pickThis = this;

      $("#pAdd").on('click', function() {
        var p = pickThis.find("#pickData option:selected");
        p.clone().appendTo("#pickListResult");
        p.remove();
      });

      $("#pAddAll").on('click', function() {
        var p = pickThis.find("#pickData option");
        p.clone().appendTo("#pickListResult");
        p.remove();
      });

      $("#pRemove").on('click', function() {
        var p = pickThis.find("#pickListResult option:selected");
        p.clone().appendTo("#pickData");
        p.remove();
      });

      $("#pRemoveAll").on('click', function() {
        var p = pickThis.find("#pickListResult option");
        p.clone().appendTo("#pickData");
        p.remove();
      });
    };
    this.getValues = function() {
      var objResult = [];
      this.find("#pickListResult option").each(function() {
        objResult.push({
          id: this.id,
          text: this.text
        });
      });
      return objResult;
    };
    this.init = function() {
      var pickListHtml =
        "<div class='row'>" +
        "  <div class='col-sm-5'>" +
        "    <select class='form-control pickListSelect' id='pickData' multiple></select>" +
        " </div>" +
        " <div class='col-sm-2 pickListButtons'>" +
        "   <button id='pAdd' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>" + opts.add + "</button>" +
        "      <button id='pAddAll' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>" + opts.addAll + "</button>" +
        "   <button id='pRemove' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>" + opts.remove + "</button>" +
        "   <button id='pRemoveAll' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>" + opts.removeAll + "</button>" +
        " </div>" +
        " <div class='col-sm-5'>" +
        "    <select class='form-control pickListSelect' id='pickListResult' multiple></select>" +
        " </div>" +
        "</div>";

      this.append(pickListHtml);

      this.fill();
      this.controll();
    };

    this.init();
    return this;
  };

  $.fn.pickList.defaults = {
    add: 'Add',
    addAll: 'Add All',
    remove: 'Remove',
    removeAll: 'Remove All'
  };


}(jQuery));


var val = {
  01: {
    id: 01,
    text: 'Isis'
  },
  02: {
    id: 02,
    text: 'Sophia'
  },
  03: {
    id: 03,
    text: 'Alice'
  },
  04: {
    id: 04,
    text: 'Isabella'
  },
  05: {
    id: 05,
    text: 'Manuela'
  },
  06: {
    id: 06,
    text: 'Laura'
  },
  07: {
    id: 07,
    text: 'Luiza'
  },
  08: {
    id: 08,
    text: 'Valentina'
  },
  09: {
    id: 09,
    text: 'Giovanna'
  },
  10: {
    id: 10,
    text: 'Maria Eduarda'
  },
  11: {
    id: 11,
    text: 'Helena'
  },
  12: {
    id: 12,
    text: 'Beatriz'
  },
  13: {
    id: 13,
    text: 'Maria Luiza'
  },
  14: {
    id: 14,
    text: 'Lara'
  },
  15: {
    id: 15,
    text: 'Julia'
  }
};

var pick = $("#pickList").pickList({
  data: val
});

$("#getSelected").click(function() {
  console.log(pick.getValues());
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/8ek53b1f/118/)